# STL Vector: undefined behaviour when calling data() on a temporary?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Does anybody have an explanation for this behaviour?

My code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Packet {

private:
    vector<unsigned char> data;

public:
    vector<unsigned char> getRawBlock() const {
        return data;
    }

    Packet() {
        data.push_back('a');
        data.push_back('b');
    }
};

int main() {
    Packet packet;
    cout << "vector byte0: " << packet.getRawBlock().at(0) << ", byte1: " << packet.getRawBlock().at(1) << endl;

    unsigned char *badBytes = packet.getRawBlock().data();
    cout << "bad byte0: " << badBytes[0] << ", byte1: " << badBytes[1] << endl;

    vector<unsigned char> copy = packet.getRawBlock();
    unsigned char *goodBytes = copy.data();
    cout << "good byte0: " << goodBytes[0] << ", byte1: " << goodBytes[1] << endl;
}
```

My output:

```
vector byte0: a, byte1: b
bad byte0: @, byte1: 0
good byte0: a, byte1: b
```

Question: Why are my "bad bytes" corrupted? I would have (naively) suspected both "badBytes" and "goodBytes" to return exactly what I put in the vector.

Comment: You said it yourself: it's a temporary. So when it's released the pointer to the data is no longer pointing to something living.

Comment: Temporaries die at the semicolon. It is toast before you get a chance to display it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unsigned char *badBytes = packet.getRawBlock().data();
```

`badBytes` gets invalid once the temporary return value of `getRawBlock()` gets destroyed (here that is at the end of the statement).

Instead you could return a `const`-reference:

```
vector<unsigned char> const& getRawBlock() const {
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why are my "bad bytes" corrupted?

Because the temporary was destroyed at the end of the line, leaving the pointer dangling. Accessing it gives undefined behaviour.

> I would have (naively) suspected both "badBytes" and "goodBytes" to return exactly what I put in the vector.

They both returned a pointer to what you put in the vector. That pointer is only valid until the vector is modified or destroyed.

Depending on how your class is intended to be used, you might want to return a reference (perhaps `const`), rather than a copy of the vector. That will remain valid as long as the `Packet` object exists.

Answer (score 1):

getRawBlock() returns a r-value, which is destroyed just after this line is executed:

```
unsigned char *badBytes = packet.getRawBlock().data();
```

So badBytes points on unallocated data, when you are dereferencing it in the next line. Undefined behavior.